# Docker container not responding to anything

Tags: docker

I'm having a major issue in `Docker`. After I `docker ps`:

```
docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                          COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                        PORTS                                                                                                NAMES
15f3bfef906f        jaguar_celery                  "bash -c 'celery -..."   7 weeks ago         Up 3 days                                                                                                                          jaguar_celery_1
```

Clearly it's running but when I `docker exec -it 15f3bfef906f bash`. This is the result:

```
rpc error: code = 2 desc = oci runtime error: exec failed: cannot exec a container that has run and stopped
```

I tried restarting the container but when I restart the `STATUS` is still `up 3 days`

**I even tried stopping the container but the conainer still remains even after** `docker ps`

Seems like nothing is changing!

**This is what is happening on my docker stats as well**

```
CONTAINER           CPU %               MEM USAGE / LIMIT       MEM %               NET I/O             BLOCK I/O           PIDS
15f3bfef906f        --                  -- / --                 --                  --                  --                  --
```

Please help! I do not know what to do anymore

**UPDATE**

**docker inspect output**

```
[
    {
        "Id": "15f3bfef906fb455f5eff42e8793b0325fb5a3cd679c2d338b589fe0c6ac9d5d",
        "Created": "2017-04-29T07:08:50.005736988Z",
        "Path": "bash",
        "Args": [
            "-c",
            "celery -A jaguar worker -Q create_account -l info & celery -A jaguar worker -B -Q others,login,get_balance,delete_expire -l info"
        ],
        "State": {
            "Status": "running",
            "Running": true,
            "Paused": false,
            "Restarting": false,
            "OOMKilled": false,
            "Dead": false,
            "Pid": 4494,
            "ExitCode": 0,
            "Error": "",
            "StartedAt": "2017-06-15T09:27:22.617660265Z",
            "FinishedAt": "2017-06-15T09:27:21.570596108Z"
        },
        "Image": "sha256:a4488611c50db37ab312b233fbf8c303e23b4b8ae6eb7636258dc7a4d778e35c",
        "ResolvConfPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/15f3bfef906fb455f5eff42e8793b0325fb5a3cd679c2d338b589fe0c6ac9d5d/resolv.conf",
        "HostnamePath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/15f3bfef906fb455f5eff42e8793b0325fb5a3cd679c2d338b589fe0c6ac9d5d/hostname",
        "HostsPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/15f3bfef906fb455f5eff42e8793b0325fb5a3cd679c2d338b589fe0c6ac9d5d/hosts",
        "LogPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/15f3bfef906fb455f5eff42e8793b0325fb5a3cd679c2d338b589fe0c6ac9d5d/15f3bfef906fb455f5eff42e8793b0325fb5a3cd679c2d338b589fe0c6ac9d5d-json.log",
        "Name": "/jaguar_celery_1",
        "RestartCount": 0,
        "Driver": "aufs",
        "MountLabel": "",
        "ProcessLabel": "",
        "AppArmorProfile": "",
        "ExecIDs": [
            "d0f45df60131c3082e74c2ce4cc0c967582e2d46cfa6916e4b171e8696992312",
            "570f4b49b7e064139712bf0181db713718433a610132452a19cfefcd027dbe3d",
            "1de4fab499857408c4004b73356f6e4c5d1167c1dd0d26494b816b76dfe8447c",
            "05e502caee3b5e75a6a363f3c347dc2ca741ebe74cffcc23c00605681dc4a75a",
            "60db3ff3277a073f3f6ba6f1b566670586f796847150023dfaf8b956f6525d6c",
            "a0b8a4ed4c0cdb2a9ba6f284ddffa83993e13c454f233e2632419bf5b91a2d2e",
            "4fdceed8ba654f6817a782edb050dc1efe988353247038ef57a9d71252c26811",
            "76824c7dc33173733dccad250e9a8a5d3769a90e0f95e3516ec157e54ed16230",
            "c8bb4a9255b80760e4520d805fb2797b5c82a33942251767828192c477b3ee47",
            "83d161f716fd8352ecaa8c0da06a653a9c20b1efd20a1c5b53720484821e230d",
            "f58b2797b4206b588955b7a22ff3ab5b64358b89e4e98b3b18bcf765da818443",
            "1bafd9b0527c1a252797929d8208027c7ad8333600e8401935ec01c084933f1d"
        ],
        "HostConfig": {
            "Binds": [],
            "ContainerIDFile": "",
            "LogConfig": {
                "Type": "json-file",
                "Config": {}
            },
            "NetworkMode": "default",
            "PortBindings": {},
            "RestartPolicy": {
                "Name": "",
                "MaximumRetryCount": 0
            },
            "AutoRemove": false,
            "VolumeDriver": "",
            "VolumesFrom": [
                "4a9c4193082aa0051937789c37dc923db5e93277e0ebea3a85d3852922f2235a:rw"
            ],
            "CapAdd": null,
            "CapDrop": null,
            "Dns": [],
            "DnsOptions": [],
            "DnsSearch": [],
            "ExtraHosts": null,
            "GroupAdd": null,
            "IpcMode": "",
            "Cgroup": "",
            "Links": [
                "/jaguar_postgres_1:/jaguar_celery_1/jaguar_postgres_1",
                "/jaguar_postgres_1:/jaguar_celery_1/postgres",
                "/jaguar_postgres_1:/jaguar_celery_1/postgres_1",
                "/jaguar_redis_1:/jaguar_celery_1/jaguar_redis_1",
                "/jaguar_redis_1:/jaguar_celery_1/redis",
                "/jaguar_redis_1:/jaguar_celery_1/redis_1"
            ],
            "OomScoreAdj": 0,
            "PidMode": "",
            "Privileged": false,
            "PublishAllPorts": false,
            "ReadonlyRootfs": false,
            "SecurityOpt": null,
            "UTSMode": "",
            "UsernsMode": "",
            "ShmSize": 67108864,
            "Runtime": "runc",
            "ConsoleSize": [
                0,
                0
            ],
            "Isolation": "",
            "CpuShares": 0,
            "Memory": 0,
            "NanoCpus": 0,
            "CgroupParent": "",
            "BlkioWeight": 0,
            "BlkioWeightDevice": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadIOps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteIOps": null,
            "CpuPeriod": 0,
            "CpuQuota": 0,
            "CpuRealtimePeriod": 0,
            "CpuRealtimeRuntime": 0,
            "CpusetCpus": "",
            "CpusetMems": "",
            "Devices": null,
            "DiskQuota": 0,
            "KernelMemory": 0,
            "MemoryReservation": 0,
            "MemorySwap": 0,
            "MemorySwappiness": -1,
            "OomKillDisable": false,
            "PidsLimit": 0,
            "Ulimits": null,
            "CpuCount": 0,
            "CpuPercent": 0,
            "IOMaximumIOps": 0,
            "IOMaximumBandwidth": 0
        },
        "GraphDriver": {
            "Name": "aufs",
            "Data": null
        },
        "Mounts": [
            {
                "Name": "67a4d02521de864af1dc28be604edb153f933c08e4f4342971935dbae32d4756",
                "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/67a4d02521de864af1dc28be604edb153f933c08e4f4342971935dbae32d4756/_data",
                "Destination": "/usr/logs",
                "Driver": "local",
                "Mode": "",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": ""
            },
            {
                "Name": "16fcd0464a2f886994f6763c45925e778707704bfdb2734499fd944675ec062a",
                "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/16fcd0464a2f886994f6763c45925e778707704bfdb2734499fd944675ec062a/_data",
                "Destination": "/usr/src/app",
                "Driver": "local",
                "Mode": "",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": ""
            },
            {
                "Name": "20b9d5fcbb71502c9d543de43f541252308dbf075d27364f38ba7b6ede885a23",
                "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/20b9d5fcbb71502c9d543de43f541252308dbf075d27364f38ba7b6ede885a23/_data",
                "Destination": "/usr/src/app/static",
                "Driver": "local",
                "Mode": "",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": ""
            }
        ],
        "Config": {
            "Hostname": "15f3bfef906f",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "PGDATABASE=postgres",
                "CDN_HOSTNAME=http://xxxwe.net",
                "HTTPS=on",
                "PGHOST=postgres",
                "DB_PORT=5432",
                "DB_PASS=xxxx",
                "PGPASSWORD=xxxx",
                "DB_NAME=postgres",
                "AWS_BUCKET_NAME=xxxx",
                "ENV=production",
                "AWS_PREFIX_FILE_NAME=production",
                "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=xxxx",
                "SITE_PREFIX=vnsr",
                "COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=jaguar",
                "WHITELIST=13.75.28.94:8001",
                "AWS_REGION=ap-southeast-1",
                "AWS_FOLDER_NAME=jaguar",
                "PGUSER=postgres",
                "DB_USER=postgres",
                "PGPORT=5432",
                "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=xxxxx",
                "DB_SERVICE=postgres",
                "PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
                "LANG=C.UTF-8",
                "GPG_KEY=C01E1CAD5EA2C4F0B8E3571504C367C218ADD4FF",
                "PYTHON_VERSION=2.7.13",
                "PYTHON_PIP_VERSION=9.0.1"
            ],
            "Cmd": [
                "bash",
                "-c",
                "celery -A jaguar worker -Q create_account -l info & celery -A jaguar worker -B -Q others,login,get_balance,delete_expire -l info"
            ],
            "Image": "jaguar_celery",
            "Volumes": null,
            "WorkingDir": "/usr/src/app",
            "Entrypoint": null,
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": {
                "com.docker.compose.config-hash": "7bff2a0b095ff5ea0574567fde47eeb8d9217d455519624a39def2eb96519292",
                "com.docker.compose.container-number": "1",
                "com.docker.compose.oneoff": "False",
                "com.docker.compose.project": "jaguar",
                "com.docker.compose.service": "celery",
                "com.docker.compose.version": "1.11.2"
            }
        },
        "NetworkSettings": {
            "Bridge": "",
            "SandboxID": "c8e514625a90f509702aefea38c8453f280ed51fde5fbd90a202c5b3ec8661b5",
            "HairpinMode": false,
            "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
            "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "Ports": {},
            "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/c8e514625a90",
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
            "EndpointID": "7b22bcba1268f144ec4ec22ed33c0c4f6c47ffa2b98bd4ebcad9d78bf94867a6",
            "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "IPAddress": "172.17.0.3",
            "IPPrefixLen": 16,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:03",
            "Networks": {
                "bridge": {
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": null,
                    "NetworkID": "ad82d85d7724ae87ca3f72337b275997ae95a56691aea406d79c38082f97fe07",
                    "EndpointID": "7b22bcba1268f144ec4ec22ed33c0c4f6c47ffa2b98bd4ebcad9d78bf94867a6",
                    "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
                    "IPAddress": "172.17.0.3",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:03"
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

**Docker info**

```
Containers: 8
 Running: 7
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 1
Images: 39
Server Version: 1.13.1
Storage Driver: aufs
 Root Dir: /var/lib/docker/aufs
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Dirs: 115
 Dirperm1 Supported: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins: 
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: aa8187dbd3b7ad67d8e5e3a15115d3eef43a7ed1
runc version: 9df8b306d01f59d3a8029be411de015b7304dd8f
init version: 949e6fa
Security Options:
 apparmor
 seccomp
  Profile: default
Kernel Version: 4.4.0-79-generic
Operating System: Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 4
Total Memory: 27.48 GiB
Name: vnsr
ID: C5UR:5IDL:OV5K:4UTS:3XMZ:2MI7:PVYH:M5MF:32PZ:5QC6:TSG7:5DXC
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
WARNING: No swap limit support
Labels:
 provider=azure
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false
```

Comment: Do you actually need to get into this container, or can you just kill/rm and launch a new one?

Comment: I need this container and I cannot kill it

Comment: Can you edit the question with the output of `docker inspect 15f3bfef906f`?

Comment: Question updated..

Comment: oops, looks like you have some secret keys in the environment there, sorry I didn't think to warn about censoring that. Please revoke those keys ASAP

Comment: I just did do not worry

Comment: Fixed by restarting the machine

Answer (score 1):

Can you also try running instead of `bash` in the exec command a `ps uax` to see if celery runs and how much CPU/Memory it consumes?

In addition, please check what happens if you run `docker logs -f 15f3bfef906f` to see what is going on inside celery queue and potentially what causes this behaviour.

Reading your comments and looking at the issue:
https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/25381

There might be different issues, e.g. one user writes:

> I got this error trying to exec into a container and it my case it was also a result of not having enough space in the thinpool.
>
> lvs showed there was some space in the thinpool on all the servers in the swarm but exec started working after I ran:

```
/usr/bin/docker rmi `/usr/bin/docker images -qa`
```

But probably you'll need to downgrade docker to previous version.

I suggest to carefully read the issues:

- https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/25381
- https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/22746

It seems like what helps one user does not work for the other.

Comment: `docker logs -f 15f3bfef906f` this became empty. But earlier this morning it was so full of logs.

`docker-compose exec celery ps aux` returned this `rpc error: code = 2 desc = oci runtime error: exec failed: cannot exec a container that has run and stopped`

Comment: Do you have enough space in your container? How do you restart it? With the `docker restart` command?

Comment: `docker-compose restart` or `docker restart`. I'm pretty certain that I should have enough space with it. I did not actually set any limit on my container.. My memory limit is `27.48GiB`

Comment: Here is stated: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/22746 _"
I faced with same error. After service docker restart all work correctly."_ Can you restart Docker service to test this?

Comment: Is it the same as restarting the docker-machine?

Comment: No, physical Linux service. On ubuntu smth. like: `sudo service restart docker` or rebooting the instance. The only cure right now is to downgrade the docker service.

Comment: I'm not really sure when you said downgrade the docker service but I'm only using containers. The docker service that I know is from docker swarm

Comment: downgrade means rolling back to a previous docker version, i.e. removing the current version and installing a previous one.

Comment: Fixed by restarting the machine

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this may be [a bug](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/27540) with Docker versions around 1.12. Is there particular data you need out of this container, or why is it not OK to restart this container?

Comment: I just added a `docker info` and according to the info.. mine is docker 1.13.1.. Actually, this is already a live production so building again may take some time as we relied on just `docker cp`

Comment: Ah, so probably not that particular bug. If there is no data you need to access, and it's just a problem of downtime, there should not be that much downtime from restarting the container. You do not need to rebuild, the image is already cached on the host, and celery launches fairly fast in my experience.

Comment: The problem is restarting does not do anything. Already tried that.. Funny thing is I tried stopping the container but it shows in `docker ps` a STATE of "Up"

Comment: Something is out of sync on the host, I guess. You could try manually killing the pid 4494 on the host, to see if that clears it out. If that leaves a zombie still, I would try restarting the daemon and/or rebooting the server.

Comment: Fixed by restarting the machine

Answer (score 1):

check docker is running or not:

```
systemctl status docker
```

if so *dead*, force to run at first boot up:

```
systemctl enable docker
```

then start it:

```
systemctl start docker
```

Answer (score 0):

At first check the container status

```
docker ps -a
```

For me the status was exited . Then start and attach the containers

```
docker start -i "my container id" .
```